# openldap substring search abnormally slow

Tags: openldap

We've got an old ldap system running openldap 2.4.23 on centos 6.4 that exhibits odd behavior:  there are only 43,000 records in the db and an sn search takes 90 seconds (only wildcard searches after I indexed sn - non-wildcard searches take a fraction of a second.  I can grep the 40M slapcat'd text file in 2.5 seconds - why would slapd take so long?

Here's slapd.conf with some sensitive bits removed:

```
include     /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/peak.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/radius.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/sendmail.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/spf.schema
include     /etc/openldap/schema/sudo.schema
allow bind_v2
loglevel    sync stats2
monitoring  off
sizelimit   unlimited
threads     32
pidfile     /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile    /var/run/openldap/slapd.args
access to attrs=userPassword
...
access to attrs=peakInternetSecretAnswer
...
access to attrs=peakInternetSecretQuestion
...
access to *
...
database    bdb
suffix      "dc=peak, dc=org"
dbconfig set_cachesize 0 1048576 0
dbconfig set_lg_bsize 4097152
dbconfig set_lg_max 16777216
cachesize   10000
dncachesize 10000
idlcachesize    10000
rootdn      "cn=Directory Manager, dc=peak, dc=org"
directory   /var/db/openldap
index   objectClass     eq
index   uid         pres,eq,sub,approx
index   sudoUser        pres,eq
index   mailLocalAddress    pres,eq,approx
index   cn          pres,eq
index   sn          pres,eq
index   mail            pres,eq
index   mailRoutingAddress  pres,eq,approx
index   mailHost        pres,eq
index   sendmailMTAKey      pres,eq
index   sendmailMTACluster  pres,eq
index   sendmailMTAMapName  pres,eq
index   sendmailMTAHost     pres,eq
index   sendmailMTAClassName    pres,eq
index   peakInternetAccountNumber   eq
index   peakInternetAccountState    eq
index   dc          pres,eq
index   peakInternetMailQuota   pres
index   entryCSN,entryUUID  eq
```

Comment: Wildcard searches where the `*` is at the beginning require a full table scan. However 90 seconds does seem excessive. More information please.

Comment: Exactly - I expect them to be slower that other queries, but not slower than grepping the text.  I'm not sure what other info you might want, but I've added slapd.conf to the question...

Comment: You should use `approx` on all the indexes you intend to use wildcards on.

Comment: I added that, stopped the server, rebuilt the index, then started the server, with no change.